# How can I get MySQL to run queries on an interval?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a web application where every row of a table needs to be processed. I'm spawning one child PHP process per table row. I'm implementing a safety mechanism, so if a PHP process is interrupted processing a row, a new PHP process will spawned to process said row. To do this I'm going to create a new table where all PHP processes check in every 10 seconds or so. I need MySQL to delete all rows that haven't been checked into for 5 minutes or more, so my application will know to create a new PHP child to process that row.

I know it's possible to get MySQL to run queries on an interval, but I don't know how.

~Enter stackoverflow~

---

Edit: I was hoping to learn how to do this 100% MySQL. Is there no way to set MySQL to run a query every hour, or at a specific time each day or such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> MySQL Events are tasks that run according to a schedule. Therefore, we sometimes refer to them as scheduled events. ... Conceptually, this is similar to the idea of the Unix crontab (also known as a “cron job”) or the Windows Task Scheduler.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

And here is the lovely syntax:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Answer (score 6):

Crontab. You can run the query directly using the mysql client (`mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname -e 'query here'`) or schedule a PHP script which runs the query.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE checked_into < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to run MySQL queries on a certain interval would be to set up a cron job.  Assuming you've got full access to your webserver, this should be doable.  You'd just make a PHP page that does the SQL operations you want to occur every X time interval, and then set the script to run on that interval via cron jobs.  More specifics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html), first introduced in MySQL 5.1.

On a side note, maybe you should redesign your program a little to avoid the extra layer of event scheduler:
Instead of deleting a row, where a process has not checked in for a while, just have a column with a check in timestamp. Then if some row has a very old check in timestamp, you can spawn a new PHP process for it.